# Что делает функция gcd?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>


using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

ll gcd(ll a, ll b) {
    return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0); // для ускорения ввода
    cin.tie(0);

    int N;
    cin >> N;
    ll a[64];
    unordered_set<ll> total;
    for (int ff = 0, nff = 0; cin >> a[ff++]; ff = nff, nff = 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < ff; ++i) {
            total.insert(a[nff] = gcd(a[i], a[ff - 1]));
            if (!nff || a[nff] != a[nff - 1]) ++nff;
        }
    cout << total.size() << endl;
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое:

```
ll gcd(ll a, ll b)
{ 
    return b?gcd(b,a%b):a;
}
```

а то я c++ плохо знаю, а в разборе задачи попадается такая вещь

Comment: отсутствие форматирования кода?

Comment: gcd = наибольший общий делитель. Писать вот так рекурсивно я не люблю, но в целом компилятор оптимизирует.

Comment: Видимо рекурсивный вызов функции самой себя + тернарный оператор.

Comment: @Spark74 я не думаю что вам ответят _зачем_ нужен этот цикл. Вы взяли решение задачи с какого-нибудь codeforces или подобного и просите нас объяснить почему тут всё так странно? Разбор там пишется словами, код это всего-лишь пример.

Answer (score 3):

Интересующая вас функция возвращает [Наибольший общий делитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). Функция реализована по рекурсивному алгоритму определения НОД. Выбранный алгоритм является не безопасным (см. [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/205106/)).
Возможно, вас смутил [Тернарный оператор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F),

```
return b?gcd(b,a%b):a;
```

ее можно заменить на:

```
if(b != 0)
   return gcd(b,a%b);
else
   return a;
```

Answer (score -3):

тернарный условный оператор C++
Алгоритм Евклида нахождения НОД (наибольшего общего делителя)
вот сайт для объяснения:
https://e-maxx.ru/algo/euclid_algorithm

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)